# How to get files list downloaded with scp -r

Tags: bash, scp

Is it possible to get files list that were downloaded using `scp -r` ?

Example:

```
$ scp -r $USERNAME@HOSTNAME:~/backups/ .

3.tar    100%    5     0.0KB/s   00:00    
2.tar    100%    5     0.0KB/s   00:00    
1.tar    100%    4     0.0KB/s   00:00
```

Expected result:

```
3.tar
2.tar
1.tar
```

Comment: try to use a combination between `history` and `grep`. This will only list files downloaded from current session.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The output that `scp` generates does not seem to come out on any of the standard streams (stdout or stderr), so capturing it directly may be difficult. One way you could do this would be to make `scp` output verbose information (by using the `-v` switch) and then capture and process this information. The verbose information is output on stderr, so you will need to capture it using the `2>` [redirection operator](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/io-redirection.html).

For example, to capture the verbose output do:

```
scp -rv $USERNAME@HOSTNAME:~/backups/ . 2> scp.output
```

Then you will be able to filter this output with something like this:

```
awk '/Sending file/ {print $NF}' scp.output
```

The `awk` command simply prints the last word on the relevant line. If you have spaces in your filenames then you may need to come up with a more robust filter.

Comment: Unfortunately, this approach also omits errors from the output if any occur, which hides them as part of any automated process.

Answer (score 1):

I realise that you asked the question about `scp`, but I will give you an alternative solution to the problem *Copy files recursively from a server using ssh, and getting the file names that are copied*.

The `scp` solution has at least one problem: if you copy lots of files, it takes a while as each file generates a *transaction*.  Instead of `scp`, I use `ssh` and `tar`:

```
ssh $USERNAME@HOSTNAME:~/backups/ "cd ~/backups/ && tar -cf - ." | tar -xf -
```

With that, adding a `tee` and a `tar -t` gives you what you need:

```
ssh $USERNAME@HOSTNAME:~/backups/ "cd ~/backups/ && tar -cf - ." | tee >(tar -xf -) | tar -tf - > file_list
```

Note that it might not work in all shell (bash is ok) as the `>(...)` construct (process substitution) is not a general option.  If you do not have it in your shell you could use a fifo (basically what the process substitution allows but shorter):

```
mkfifo tmp4tar
(tar -xf tmp4tar ; rm tmp4tar;) &
ssh $USERNAME@HOSTNAME:~/backups/ "cd ~/backups/ && tar -cf - ." | tee -a tmp4tar | tar -tf - > file_list
```

Answer (score 1):

```
scp -v -r yourdir orczhou@targethost:/home/orczhou/ \
2> >(awk '{if($0 ~ "Sending file modes:")print $6}')
```

with -v "Sending file modes: C0644 7864 a.sql" should be ouput to stderr

use 'awk' to pick out the file list